# Get array from database and save as variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

Looking for a bit of help.

i have the following code

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM invoices");


while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

 $id = $row["id"];
 $date = $row["date"];
 $companyname = $row["company_name"];
 $service = $row["service"];
 $cost = $row["cost"];

 }
```

$service and $cost are saved as an array.

at the moment if i output as $cost i get 100,200,300,400 etc, basically getting everything.

what i want to do is save each one as their own variable automatically.

its being used for an invoice so if there is more than one service it will list them on each line. i want to save it as a variable so i can input it into an invoice template i have already created.

any help appreciated.

Comment: `100,200,300,400` Seems more like your database is not normalized!

Comment: You need to see what data is in there to start with. I doubt this is a PHP problem.

Comment: could you show us `invoces` structure? `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the cost is a list of cost for that company. Since they are seperated by commas you can use the [explode](http://php.net/EXPLODE) method.

```
$cost = explode(',', $row['cost']);
```

This will take the string `100,200,300,400` and convert it into an array.